# Fitch Logic Proof

Tags: logic, philosophy

I am stumped on this proof. I have attached a link with my proof so far.

I'm not sure how to derive a contradiction from WeakPref(a,b) on line 12.

[image: My proof so far]

Comment: Use negation introduction there.

Comment: Did the advice help?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you for your help! However, I'm still stuck deriving a contradiction. I'm thinking of obtaining ~StrongPref(b,a) from StrongPref(a,b) ⟷ ~WeakPref(b,a) and WeakPref(a,b), but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Is StrongPref(a,b) ↔ StrongPref(b,a) an assumption?

Comment: Use *Universal Elimination* on premise 3: $\forall x~\forall y~(\textsf{StrongPref}(x,y)\leftrightarrow\lnot\textsf{WeakPref}(y,x))$ to obtain a *useful* biconditional to use with the *assumptions* of $\textsf{StrongPref}(b,a)$ and $\textsf{WeakPref}(a,b)$ .

Comment: Thank you! I solved it. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way to go!   You are almost spot on the ball.   What you need to do *at line 12* is assume $\def\S{\mathsf{StrongPref}}\def\W{\mathsf{WeakPref}}\W(a,b)$, assume $\S(b,a)$, derive a contradiction, therefore introducing a negation so you may thereby use it in the disjunction elimination. 
$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\def\S{\mathsf{StrongPref}}\def\W{\mathsf{WeakPref}}\def\too{\leftrightarrow}
\fitch{~5.~\S(a,b)}{~6.~\S (a,b)\too\neg \W(b,a)\\~7.~\neg\W(b,a)\\~8.~\W(a,b)\vee \W(b,a)\\\fitch{~9.~\W(b,a)}{10.~\bot\\11.~\neg \S(b,a)}\\{\color{red}{\fitch{12.~\W(a,b)}{\fitch{13.~\S(b,a)}{~~\vdots\\~~\vdots\\16.~\bot}\\17.~\lnot\S(b,a)}}}\\18.~\neg \S(b,a)}$$